# Keychain sync on Mac and iPhone

Tags: ios, macos, keychain

I have a MacBook (10.12.6) and an iPhone  (IOS 10.3.3).

I configured Safari to save my passwords on websites, and I changed the default password of 'login' on keychain.

This way, the only way to see the saved password on Safari is using this master password I set on 'login' item on keychain.

My problem is the iPhone's Safari does not know the password I saved on my MacBook's Safari.

Both my MacBook and iPhone uses the same iCloud account, and the bookmark and history is in sync.

The only thing is not working is the password.

Is it a limitation on IOS or it should work with that setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login keychain is a local keychain on your Mac and doesn’t sync to iOS. To use iCloud Keychain, you need to store passwords in the iCloud keychain which should be shown next to the login one in Keychain Access if you have the iCloud service enabled in System Preferences.

Comment: On Keychain Access I have this itens: login, Local Itens, System and System Roots. I can see all the safari passwords on 'Local Itens'. On iCloud Preference the Safari is checked both on my Mac and iPhone

Comment: @ricardo Keychain is separate to Safari in iCloud preferences on iOS and macOS, can you check that service too?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have to check 'KeyChain' on iCloud preferences. Thanks,